# How are we importing widget here in this document?

Tags: python, python-unittest

While reading this unittest [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) , which I'm trying to follow locally in my system. But I failed to resolve the following line

```
widget = Widget('The widget')
```

in

```
class DefaultWidgetSizeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        widget = Widget('The widget')
        self.assertEqual(widget.size(), (50, 50), 'incorrect default size')
```

How did they import Widget? is it tkinter import? But that too didnt resolve as it was asking for

> unfilled widgetName

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: That's not necessarily a real thing, just example code to show how you might go about testing something. There is a [`ttk.Widget`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html?highlight=widget#widget), but it *"is not supposed to be directly instantiated"*.

Comment: Kivy has a `Widget` class, however, as @jonrsharpe has pointed out, it's just a sample code and you needn't use the same scenario.

Comment: ok I get it. Let me use custom scenarios. An earlier example was working. I thought this will work too. Thanks @jonrshapre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import it the same way you always `import` something. That step has simply been omitted in that sample code, since the sample is about `unittest`, not `Widget`. "Widget" was chosen as a generic thingamabob that stands in for whatever you want to test.